# Ecto query where testA and (testB or testC)

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a schema that looks like this;

```
schema "things" do
  field(:title, :string)
  field(:temperature, :integer)
  field(:weight, :integer)
end
```

I'd like to write an Ecto query that is equivalent to the following SQL, but I can't seem to get it into a valid form.

```
select * from things where temperature <= 200 and (weight is null or weight > 2);
```

How can I do this in Ecto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost the same syntax as SQL:

```
from(t in Thing, where: t.temperature <= 200 and (is_nil(t.weight) or t.weight > 2))
```